# Which framework should I use to implement REST API that includes authorization

Tags: rest, neo4j, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am trying to build a social networking site/app.After some research the conclusion I reached was to use a Graph Database. `Neo4j` is the most mature and used Graph database

Now I need to provide authentication and authorization to the database and I want to authenticate using `OAuth` so as to authenticate via `facebook/google`.

The problem I am facing is that I want to use the  `REST API` which provides data on the basis of a person's authorization but I am not able to decide which framework/tool to use. I want this framework/tool to be fast,reliable and scalable.

Comment: in which programming language?

Comment: I know python and java. If required I can learn the programing language

Answer (score 1):

The choice of a framework is quite a matter of taste on a person basis.

For Python you have Django and Spring for Java, both offers OAuth.

Now, this has nothing to do with your database, a user will never be connected to the database.

Also, a framework will not make your development life easier in the first 12 months, learning a framework takes time, and security is a hot topic and you need to learn all the little tricks of that specific framework.

In the meantime, you'll have to learn Neo4j and his integration with your framework.

> I want this framework/tool to be fast,reliable and scalable

I think, depending of your development skills, that attending a fast, reliable and scalable application state with a framework you need to learn and a database you need to learn, this should take approximately two years.